# React esLinter errors reported

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I have code :

```
    render() {
    const self = this;
//error on this line        const options = self.props.options.map(function (option) {
     return (
       <option
      key={option[self.props.optionValue]}
      value={option[self.props.optionValue]}
    >
      {option[self.props.optionLabel]}
    </option>
  );
});
return (
  <DropDownSimpleStyled
    closeStatus={this.state.closeStatus}
    value={this.getValue}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    onClick={this.changeCloseStatus}
  >
    {options}
  </DropDownSimpleStyled>);
```

}

I am getting errors:

> message: 'Unexpected function expression. (prefer-arrow-callback)'
>
> message: 'Missing function expression name. (func-names)'
>
> source: 'eslint'

What does it mean ? How should i re-write code to be `eslinter` compliant ? Did i miss something ?

Answer (score 1):

Prefer the arrow notation : http://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-arrow-callback

```
const options = self.props.options.map(function (option) {
  [...]
});
```

Is replaced by :

```
const options = self.props.options.map((option) => {
  [...]
});
```

Or when handling a SINGLE statement (note the implicit `return`) :

```
const options = self.props.options.map(option => (
  <option
    key={option[self.props.optionValue]}
    value={option[self.props.optionValue]}
  >
    {option[self.props.optionLabel]}
  </option>
));
```

More in depth explanations about arrow function notation best practices : https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#arrow-functions

It will correct both problems, as arrow functions are always anonymous.

http://eslint.org/docs/rules/func-names requires you to name your functions, so instead of `function(option) {}` you would have to name it, such as function `function mapOptions(option) {}`, for exemple. Both notations (arrow function and named function) should be accepted, depending on your ruleset.

Comment: yep, i tried that , but i am getting this: 
message: 'Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body. (arrow-
source: 'eslint'

Comment: Yes sorry, when your function only contains 1 statement you should not use the braces:
I will edit my answer

Comment: Yep, i knew that but my linter throws en error telling me i should use parenthesis, i when i have it the second way, there is only one error : Unexpected block statement...

Comment: I don't know what your ruleset is, it probably wants you to wrap your option parameter with parenthesis ! My edited answer passes my linter without error / warning, with the airbnb ruleset.